# Get request with escaped " by regexp

Tags: regex

I can get full string by regexp 
    "([^"]|\")+[^\]" 
How can I get full string by regexp without 
    |

"GET /cgi-bin/nph-psf.exe?css=\">test HTTP/1.1"

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the backslash - `|\\"` and `[^\\]"`

Comment: Is there a practical reason you don't want to use `|`?  One way is: `"[^"]*(\\"[^"]*)*"`

Comment: @Lorehead the reason is that when [|] is used for processing large strings with regexp in java, java.lang.StackOverflowError appears. You were really helpful. Thanks

Comment: OK.  Didn't know that.  Should I post an answer?

Comment: @Lorehead You decide, Oh the subtle ninja of regex!

Comment: @Lorehead and what about  "CONNECT <span class=\"result\">65.113.238.149:80 HTTP/1.0"

Comment: That ought to match; one bigger problem is that mine matches \"foo\" spuriously as "foo\".  In what context should these strings match?